# sshfs is mounted, but no file shared?

Tags: 20.04, mount

I am having some issue with **sshfs**. It used to work in the same condition. I mount Downloads directory from my desktop to my laptop.

Now when I try to do it, everything seems to work fine, except no file/dir is visible in the mointpoint directory.

I use the following command to mount:

```
sshfs desktopuser@xx.xx.xx.xx:/home/laptopuser/Downloads  /home/laptopuser/mnt/mnt
```

When I cat /proc/mounts, I get this:

```
desktopuser@xx.xx.xx.xx:/home/desktopuser/Downloads  /home/laptopuser/mnt/mnt fuse.sshfs rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000 0 0
```

everything seems to work fine except I am not getting any file/directory shared. When I create a file in mointpoint, I am not getting it on desktop.

I really don't know what I am doing wrong here. Any help ?